# image uploading image in the chrome 55 having image size 2mb or more

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, image-uploading

Hi I am trying to upload the image in the Google Chrome having version 55 ,
it shows the js errors and same image uploaded using the previous version of chrome also on the mozilla , uploaded successfully.I can't understand the exact issue. Please suggest me solution if any.

```
    Console log is as follows :
    jquery.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at o (jquery.js:6)
    at gn (jquery.js:6)
    at gn (jquery.js:6)
    at gn (jquery.js:6)
    at gn (jquery.js:6)
    at Function.x.param (jquery.js:6)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.js:6)
    at init (common.js:209)
    at init.$.fn.visExecution (common.js:586)
    at init.load_module (common.js:371)
```

Comment: So this snippet you're using is working in Safari and Firefox, but not in the latest version of chrome? Do you know what request code is setup (guessing by reading the Function.ajax)? Are you sure, you did not refactor or touch the code in any way? The error does not appear with a image size below 2mb and is successfully uploaded?

Comment: without any change in the jquery this problem occur.I checked it on firefox not on the safari.

Comment: What about all my other questions? Is it working in firefox?

Comment: yes working in the firefox

Comment: image size less than 2mb uploaded successfully in same version of chrome

Comment: Can you show the script, which is uploading the image? Are there some conditions? There shouldn't be any difference between <2MB and > 2MB. Maybe you are executing the function in the wrong context.